# Joining two tables with same column names but with different data abbreviations

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Hi I have two tables Table A and Table B .

Table A has 3 columns id ,Location & name

Table B has 3 columns id , location & address

I need to join these two tables . I know we can use the location table to join . But in Table A say for Eg location has data s like Maryland , New york Etc...

But in Table B the location is in short form like MD, NY Etc...

How do i join this ????

Maryland - MD
New york- NY

Comment: Are these conversion saved anywhere (or, alternatively, can you add such a conversion table)?

Comment: You'd better add a redundant column to save the abbreviations in table A, or it becomes very inefficient because of a lack of index.

Answer (score 1):

You have to join  on a matching key between the 2 tables.

If you can get a table with both keys in a table you can use the table as a junction table.

I.E Create a table that as the Key from Table A and Key From Table B

JUNCTION TABLE(TableAKey, TableBKey)

You can then join both tables via this junction table

Comment: Thanks for the reply , But these two tables are my source from excel and i do not have the key columns for both the tables.


And i need to do this in SSIS....

Comment: It may be tedious to create this sort of a table, but you have to get the matched keys.  If this is a list of public information like city abbreviations and city full names, an Internet search may give you the list  you are looking for.  But without the keys you will not get the join to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me check.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, CASE location WHEN 'Maryland' THEN 'MD'
                              WHEN 'New york' THEN 'NY'
                    END AS StateCode
     FROM  TABLE_A) A 
INNER JOIN TABLE_B B 
ON A.StateCode = B.location
```

Answer (score 0):

Query will be

$sql = SELECT A.id,A.location,A.name,B.id,B.location AS location_B,B.Address FROM TableA A INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.id=B.id ";

u will get result from table A  with column name - location and FROM table B with column name = location_B

Thanks